# Symfony2: Problems passing parameters between pages

Tags: php, symfony

I am quite new about using Symfony 2 for developing in PHP, so i used the "Symfony Blog" example as the base of a new simple app in order to try out what i learnt.

I have got this rule defined:

```
AhorrarMainBundle_cuenta:
  pattern:  /cuenta/{id}
  defaults: { _controller: AhorrarMainBundle:Cuenta:cuenta }
  requirements:
       _method:  GET
            id: \d+
```

So i expect that when i write this address in my browser (ahorro/app_dev/cuenta/1) it launchs "cuentaAction" passing a number 1 as an argument.

This is the code  of the twig template i am using as layout:

```
{% block navigation %}
   <nav>
      <ul class="navigation">
         <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
         <li><a href="{{ path('AhorrarMainBundle_cuenta', {'id': id}) }}">Cuenta</a></li>
         <li><a href="{{ path('AhorrarMainBundle_movimientos') }}">Movimientos</a></li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
{% endblock %}
```

This is the code of the page launched when calling "ahorro/app_dev/cuenta/1":

```
{% extends "AhorrarMainBundle::base.html.twig" %}
{% block title %}Cuenta{% endblock%}
{% block body %}
    <header>
        <h1>Cuenta symAhorro</h1>
    </header>
{% endblock %}
```

Indeed, it is just a simple page i expected to be showed and nothing more. But when i try to access to any page i get this error:

![Error image] http://imageshack.com/a/img837/1190/dg53.jpg

**EDITED**
This is the class i am using as controller:

```
class CuentaController extends Controller{
public function indexAction()
{
    return $this->render('AhorrarMainBundle:MainPage:index.html.twig');
}
public function cuentaAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $cuenta = $em->getRepository('AhorrarMainBundle:Cuenta')->find($id);

    if (!$cuenta) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Blog post.');
    }

    return $this->render('AhorrarMainBundle:Cuenta:cuenta.html.twig', array(
        'cuenta'      => $cuenta,
    ));
}
}
```

So seems the problem is that the "id" variable doesnt exist, but i think i followed what the "Symfony book" says about arguments...

Can anyone help me saying how should i do this? or maybe where can i find a working example?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How you are passing id to your twig view ?

Comment: Yep, show us the controller method...

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I expected that when i invoque "ahorro/app_dev/cuenta/1", number 1 is directly assigned to id

Comment: @MichaelHelwig I edited the post and added the controller class

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't specifically assign the template variable in the controller, it does not automatically exist.

You can get the request parameter named 'id' via the default request variable:

```
app.request.get( 'id' )
```

or if you want to use it in several places, assign the variable yourself:

```
{% set id = app.request.get( 'id' ) %}
```

Comment: I edited the post and added my controller class, anyway, how should i assign the template variable in the controller? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What hpoeri commented is one solution to your problem.

Another one (and, usually preferred) would be to return your `$id` variable from the controller to the view, since this is basically what the separation between controller and view is about. So your return statement within your controller should read:

```
return $this->render('AhorrarMainBundle:Cuenta:cuenta.html.twig', array(
    'cuenta'      => $cuenta,
    'id'          => $id
));
```

All variables you pass in the returned array get available in your view.

Have a look at the Symfony2 documentation here, especially the section called "Rendering Tamplates"
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#rendering-templates
and the section about "Views" which explains variable handling a little bit better here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_view.html